# Creating dynamic object in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I want to create a dynamic Key Value Object in Java Script. Such as :

```
var resonseArray = [];
var i = 0;
      for (var key in value) { 
        if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) { 
             finalObj = { i : {'keys': key , 'values' : value['key']}}};
             resonseArray.push(finalObj);
          i++;
        }
      }
```

But when I console the resonseArray, it console the i as a string not the dynamic variable i value.

Comment: What is the content of "value"?

Comment: @ViktorSarström : { aPillarLh: 'Dented',
     bPillarLh: 'Repainted',
     cPillarLh: 'Dented',
     aPillarRh: 'Repaired',
     bPillarRh: 'Dented',
     cPillarRh: 'Dented' }

Comment: why `value['key']`? I think it should be `value[key]`

Comment: Just replace `i` with `[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use bracket notation to create keys with variable

```
finalObj = {}
finalObj[i.toString()] = {'keys': key , 'values' : value['key']};
```

Comment: It works :) Thanks Buddy :)